# Want to retrieve a cookie value

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

my program generate a cookie with this code :

```
    echo "
    <script>
    $('td').click(function(){
        document.cookie=$(this).text();
        alert(document.cookie);
    });
    </script>
    ";
```

It works fine, document.cookie is the same as the td value.
However i want to call it on a php function later such as :

```
function fill_input() {
    $value = $COOKIE["document.cookie"]; 
    echo $value;
```

But it said that it is not set.
Please help me i am a student and i already spent one full day trying to figure this simple problem. Thanks you have a nice day.

Comment: Why are you using JavaScript to set the cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using document.cookie you need to set a name and a value. The way you do it the name is empty you only set a value.

```
  echo "
    <script>
    $('td').click(function(){
        document.cookie='myCookie='+$(this).text();
        alert(document.cookie);
    });
    </script>
    ";
```

Above code set the name and the value to the cookie and the you can call it like:

```
$_COOKIE["myCookie"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access your cookie by it's name, right now you're passing a string `document.cookie`.

So, whatever `$(this).text()` is, will be how you access the cookie. If it returns `blablabla`, then

```
function fill_input() {
    $value = $_COOKIE["blablabla"]; 
    echo $value;
```